# x86 Assembly: How to get values of local variables in GDB?

Tags: x86, gdb

I'm trying to dissect some code in GDB for an extra credit project. Running through the code (in Intel syntax) and I need to see what the current value is at an address on the stack - let's say [ebp-0x4]. How do I see what the value is at that address?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I see what the value is at that address?

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp-4
```

Comment: Any reason that Intel syntax uses the "$" in front of the register here? (and only here as far as I've seen)

Comment: The `$` has nothing to do with Intel syntax. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html#Registers

Answer (score 0):

you can also use print

```
print *(double*)($ebp-4)  Print double at address %ebp-4
print /t $ebp-4           Print in binary forms
```

"help x" will show you the format like "/a /w /d"....